Branch.io live keys should be private or public
I'm kind of lost in the documentation of Branch.io regarding the right implementation of Branch.io live keys, i'm merely wondering whether Branch.io live keys are safe to be embeded in client side code, mostly JS files, what's the possible security risk in doing that; if there is..
I expected to find that in the branch.io documentation, and through doing some research, i found contradicting opinions as some suggest securing the keys anyways even though, nothing much could be done with these keys other than fake linking it and harming the panel records, other just say there is no risk at all as these keys are not considered secrets..

It is strongly recommended to secure these keys instead of leaving them accessible. The securing of the key should be the same as other keys are secured either locally or through server endpoint.
On the post where it's mentioned that links can be created here is more detailed explanation to that:

Create Deeplink Api This Api only required Branch Key for link generation and hence unnecessary shortlinks would be linked through your App records if someone misuses these
Can also open additional threats were someone can try replicating the Branch SDK initialisation within their app/ webpage which would affect the analytics data

The practices followed to secure the key should be same as other SDK's and it won't cause any issue as long as the sdk is able to retrieve this key during initialisation
Please reach out to https://help.branch.io/ for any additional queries or concern.
